# setting the properties file path in java command in my script

Tags: java

I am using this command for setting the path of config file,along with the main class, but it is not working please help me out

```
java -cp %classpath% \
-Doligosoft.POSConfig.file=\
"/home/mlpc04/Paritosh/POS_3.0/resources/posconfig.properties"com.floreantpos.main.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`java -cp %classpath% -Doligosoft.POSConfig.file=/home/mlpc04/Paritosh/POS_3.0/resources/posconfig.properties com.floreantpos.main.Main`

And then in your main class just do this:

```
String configPath = System.getProperty("oligosoft.POSConfig.file");
```

It should work.

Best Luck!!